# Error when reading NSAttributedString from UITextPasteItem

Tags: uikit, uitextview, nsitemprovider

In order to support a custom paste behaviour, In my `UITextView`, which I set as its own `UITextPasteDelegate` in `awakeFromNib()`, I implemented `textPasteConfigurationSupporting(_:,transform:)`.

When pressing the paste button above the software keyboard, in the callback of `item.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.rtf.identifier)` I get an error

```
Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1000 "Cannot load representation of type public.rtf" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot load representation of type public.rtf, NSUnderlyingError=0x28374e8e0 {Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=13 "Operation not authorized." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not authorized.}}}
```

even though the `item.itemProvider.registeredTypeIdentifiers` are

```
"iOS rich content paste pasteboard type", "Apple Web Archive pasteboard type", "com.apple.uikit.attributedstring", "com.apple.rtfd", "com.apple.flat-rtfd", "public.utf8-plain-text", "public.rtf", "public.html", "com.apple.WebKit.custom-pasteboard-data"
```

and `item.itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self)` returns `true`.

Even `item.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSAttributedString.self)` returns a similar error:

```
Error Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1200 "Could not coerce an item to class NSAttributedString" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not coerce an item to class NSAttributedString, NSUnderlyingError=0x283497b70 {Error Domain=PBErrorDomain Code=13 "Operation not authorized." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not authorized.}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that I can solve the issue like this:

```
func textPasteConfigurationSupporting(_ textPasteConfigurationSupporting: UITextPasteConfigurationSupporting, transform item: UITextPasteItem) {
    if item.itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(UTType.rtf.identifier) {
        item.itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.rtf.identifier) { attributedString, error in
            if let data = attributedString as? Data, let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: data, documentAttributes: nil) {
                item.setResult(string: myOwnString(from: attributedString))
            } else {
                item.setDefaultResult()
            }
        }
    } else {
        item.setDefaultResult()
    }
}
```